# Mvc URI Structure: ID or Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uri

I am working on an application that will provide information for certain events, and am wondering what the best way to structure my URI resources is.

The easiest way is to simply use an ID for each event; such as;

Baseurl/Events/{EventId}

The issue with this is that the ID is obviously not something that will be known to the customer. I would prefer to have something more like;

Baseurl/Events/{EventName}

Perhaps a more important reason for doing this is for SEO purposes. If I am targeting a keyword for the event, surely it would be more beneficial to have the event name in the URL?

My issue with using the event name is that obviously it’s not as ‘parseable’ as an ID, in that it becomes sensitive to event name changes etc. Also adding spaces into the URI means that customers aren’t likely explore by typing resource names in, and again could lead to parsing issues.

What is the standard practice in this area? Is using an ID the norm, or using a resource name? If I take Wordpress as an example, I know that the postname can act as the resource identifier, so I know at least one instance of the name being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the hybrid approach, much like how StackOverflow is built: use the ID in the URL for your internal usage and append the name afterwards for readability and SEO.

Comment: Ah thank you, the answer was staring me in the face all along then. Just for people who come across this, the friendly URL portion is referred to as a slug, and is an empty parameter in the route (so the controller doesn't care about it).